# Grouping a set of numbers that reoccur in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe

```
holder
0
1
2
0
1
2
0
1
0
1
2
```

I want to be able to group each set of numbers that come in starting at 0, ends at the max value, assign it a value for that group.
So

```
holder  group
0        1
1        1
2        1
0        2
1        2
2        2
0        3
1        3
0        4
1        4
2        4
```

I tried:
n=3

```
df['group'] = [int(i/n) for i,x in enumerate(df.holder)]
```

But this returns

```
holder  group
0        1
1        1
2        1
0        2
1        2
2        2
0        3
1        3
0        3
1        4
2        4
```

Comment: `d.holder.diff().lt(0).cumsum()`

Comment: @d.b Nice, I added something like that to [my answer](/a/72355300/4518341) since it was already so similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming holder is monotonically nondecreasing until another 0 occurs, you can identify the zeroes and create groups by taking the cumulative sum.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'holder': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]})
# identify 0s and create groups
df['group'] = df['holder'].eq(0).cumsum()
print(df)
```

```
    holder  group
0        0      1
1        1      1
2        2      1
3        0      2
4        1      2
5        2      2
6        0      3
7        1      3
8        0      4
9        1      4
10       2      4
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each group's numbers always increase, you can check whether the numbers are less than or equal to the ones before, then take the cumulative sum, which turns the booleans into group numbers.

```
df['group'] = df['holder'].diff().le(0).cumsum() + 1
```

Result:

```
    holder  group
0        0      1
1        1      1
2        2      1
3        0      2
4        1      2
5        2      2
6        0      3
7        1      3
8        0      4
9        1      4
10       2      4
```

(I'm using `<=` specifically instead of `<` in case of two adjacent 0s.)

<sub>*This was inspired by [Nickil Maveli](/users/6207849/nickil-maveli)'s [answer](/a/41621009/4518341) on "Groupby conditional sum of adjacent rows" but the cleaner method was posted by [d.b](/users/7128934/d-b) in [a comment here](/q/72355137/72355300#comment127824750_72355137).*</sub>